# Making jslink target specific list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, jslink

**Background**
I got a page where I’m showing two list views from two separate lists which both have Custom List as their ListTemplate. They got their separate jslink file cause I don’t want them to look alike.

**Problem**
The js link file targets both listviews since they use the same Template.

**Code**

```
(function () { 
    var listContext = {}; 
    listContext.Templates = {}; 

    listContext.ListTemplateType = 100;

    listContext.Templates.Header = "<div><ul>"; 
    listContext.Templates.Footer = "</ul></div>"; 
    listContext.Templates.Item = LinkTemplate; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(listContext); 

})();
```

**Question**
Is there any way to make the js only target a specific list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with Paul Hunts solution that he writes about on myfatblog.co.uk. http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/09/listview-web-part-issues-with-jslink-and-display-templates-a-solution/

The script ended up looking like this and I pasted it into the jslink function where I define what listContext to override.

```
// Override the RenderListView once the ClientTemplates.JS has been called
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

    // Copy and override the existing RenderListView
    var oldRenderListView = RenderListView;

    RenderListView = function(ctx,webPartID)
    {
        // Check the title and set the BaseViewId
        if (ctx.ListTitle == "List")
            ctx.BaseViewID = "list";

        //now call the original RenderListView
        oldRenderListView(ctx,webPartID);
    }

},"ClientTemplates.js");
```